# How to handle npm request package deprecation

Tags: node.js, npm

How community people are planning nodejs apps maintenance with npm 'request' package dependency, since it was recently deprecated ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Thanks.

Comment: Use something else to make requests? There's a link to alternatives from the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Or just keep request until it is actually a problem, then do something about it.